# How to make autoclick for slider with setInterval?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Have such code https://jsfiddle.net/g11chp1z/7/.
how to use `timeout()` or `setInterval()` to add **autoplay**
I'm fully beginner in JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement this js time Interval, will fake a click in your slide elements

```
var flag=1;
setInterval(function(){
    var slide=document.getElementById('slide'+flag);    
  slide.click();
  flag++;
  if(flag==4) flag=1;
},2000);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/RACCH/L35b904k/

Answer (score 1):

The function below will do what you want.
Just call autoPlay() on load.

```
function autoPlay(){
        var slideId = 1;
        setInterval(function(){
      slideId++;
      document.getElementById('slide'+slideId).click();
      if(slideId == 3){
        slideId = 0;
      }
      },1000);
    }
```